# Is $ f$ bounded as $\Im z\to \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, complex-integration

Let $k$ be an integer and $\mathcal{H}$ denotes the upper half plane. Let $f: \mathcal{H}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a function satisfying the following conditions:

$1.$ $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathcal{H}$.

$2.$ $f(\frac{az+b}{cz+d})= (cz+d)^{k} f(z),$ for all $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix} \in SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ and $ z \in \mathcal{H}.$

$3.$ $f$ is given by a power series of the form,
$$ f(z)= \sum_{ n \geq 0} a_{n} q^{n} (q= e^{2\pi  i z}),$$ (Note that, the condition $2$ implies, $f$ is one periodic and hence has a Laurent series expansion.)

Can we say, that $f(z)$ is bounded as $\Im z\ \text{ to } \infty$ from the above three conditions?

I am unable to deduce this. If not, can someone tell me what should be the counterexample to this?

Comment: Hint: On the third condition, write $z=x+iy$ and see what happens to $q^n$ for  all $n\geq 1$ as $y$ tends to positive infinity

Comment: Note that $|q|=e^{-2\pi\Im(z)}$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: By the remark @TravorLZH made, notice that as $\Im(z)$ goes to positive infinity (positive is the key here) $|q|=e^{-2\pi\Im(z)}$ goes to $0$. Using this fact, together with the 3rd condition, you can bound $|f(z)|$ by $|a_0|$. In fact, one can show that $f(i\infty)=a_0$